# Can't mirror messages from Kafka producer in container to consumer

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, mirroring

I am trying to mirror a kafka topic from a provider in a container in an ec2 instance to a consumer, and messages are not coming through. I suspect that I am messing things up with the `.properties` configs, as this is my first time using MirrorMaker. I may have also messed up with pointing to the wrong ports somewhere along the way.

The would-be provider broker is running in a centOS container in an ec2 instance. The provider is receiving data from a remote MySQL server through a custom-configured jdbc source connector to a topic called `mysql-jdbc-events`. The provider is successfully receiving messages.

The would-be consumer is currently on the host ec2 instance, although that will change once it's successfully been tested. I mapped port 12181 of the host to port 2181 of the container (where zookeeper is running). I am running the MirrorMaker command from the consumer.

I ran the command

```
./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.MirrorMaker --consumer.config /path/to/config/consumer.properties --producer.config /path/to/config/producer.properties --whitelist "mysql-jdbc-events"
```

consumer.properties:

```
# format: host1:port1,host2:port2 ...
zookeeper.connect=(host ip-address):12181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=10000
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# consumer group id
group.id=mirror_group
```

producer.properties:

```
# format: host1:port1,host2:port2 ...
zookeeper.connect=(host ip-address):2181
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# specify the compression codec for all data generated: none, gzip, snappy, lz4, zstd
compression.type=none
```

I tried both with and without the `zookeeper.connect` parameter in the producer config because I found conflicting about it being necessary. I also got a warning to the effect of `WARN The configuration 'zookeeper.connect' was supplied but isn't a known config.`, but I read elsewhere on SO that this could be ignored.

I did not get any messages populated to the topic at the consumer, but there are messages in the topic at the producer.

If any more information would be helpful, please let me know.

I am also not married to this configuration - if there is a *simpler* way to keep the jdbc in the container and forward the messages to a kafka instance outside the container, that's good too.

Comment: Can you clarify your desired topology here? You have a JDBC source connector in Kafka Connect, and want to write the data to a Kafka cluster and replicate it to a different cluster, is that right?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Yes, that's correct. Right now, the topology happens to be that both clusters consist of only one broker, and they are within the same "box," but that's just for testing.

Comment: Can you explain this more " if there is a simpler way to keep the jdbc in the container and forward the messages to a kafka instance outside the container"? I'm still not clear what relevance the container has, nor JDBC? If your question is just about mirror maker then it's just topics (regardless of how they're populated). If your question is about getting data from the JDBC connector to somewhere else then please clarify that.

Comment: Please show that you can consumer alone from the location that mirror maker is running using the exact same `consumer.config`. And if you aren't using Kafka 0.8, you should not be using Zookeeper connection string at all. Plus, if you are using the JDBC connector already in a container, then you could use Replicator for a trial period, at least, to copy topics between clusters (note: there are free alternatives on Github using Connect as well)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I'm sorry if I'm not being clear. The container is relevant because we are using a docker repo to standardize and automate the installation and configuration of the MySQL --> Kafka feed. I want the JDBC connector to remain in the container because installing/configuring the connector is a big part of what is being left to docker. The only relevance of the JDBC to what I am currently trying to do is as an explanation of why my starting point is in the container. The container is relevant because I think it affects how MirrorMaker should be configured.

Comment: I am fairly sure that the JDBC connector does not impact my question, but I am often told that I did not include enough information about my configuration, so I put it in in case it is somehow relevant. I'm fairly new to Kafka, and even newer to MirrorMaker, so I figured just including the whole picture would be the safest thing to do.

Comment: @cricket_007 could you point me to one of those free alternatives? That sounds promising. Thanks!

Comment: See the list of example connectors that I iterated here - https://github.com/cricket007/schema-registry-transfer-smt